# hibernate - add relation (many-to-many)

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I have the following POJOs:

```
@Entity(name = "member")
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member {
    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int mIdentifier;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String mName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "mMembers")
    private Set<Project> mProjects = new HashSet<Project>();

    public int getIdentifier() {
        return mIdentifier;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(final String pName) {
        mName = pName;
    }

    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return mProjects;
    }

    public Member() {
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int mIdentifier;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Member> mMembers = new HashSet<Member>();

    public int getIdentifier() {
        return mIdentifier;
    }

    public Set<Member> getMembers() {
        return mMembers;
    }

    public Project() {
    }
}
```

I would like to understand why this works:

```
    Project project = new Project();
    Member member = new Member();

    member.setName("John Snow");
    project.getMembers().add(member);

    db.save(project);
    db.save(member);
```

And I would like to understand why this doesn't work:

```
    Project project = new Project();
    Member member = new Member();

    member.setName("John Snow");
    member.getProjects().add(project); // this is different

    db.save(project);
    db.save(member);
```

In the second code, there is no entry in the join table (between project and member) added.

What is common practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a bidirectional association, there is always an owner side, and an inverse side.

Hibernate only considers the owner side.

The owner side is the one which doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute.

The common practice is generally to make sure the object graph is consistent by adding a member to its project **and** the project to its member. If you only do one, then make sure to update the owner side.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Is there a way to automatically update the member when the member gets persisted? That is, `member.getProjects()` will contain the project. I am still new to Hibernate, but I have the feeling that my objects should reflect their database state without manual interventions, which are easily forgotten.

Comment: Encapsulation. Instead of modifying the entities collection from the outside, use an `addProject()` method in Member that does everything needed. Return an unmodifiable collection from `getProjects()` and `getMembers()`.

Comment: Yes, I see that. The code above left that out for simplicity. But this still requires some responsibility of the developer. There is no way to auto-update the relation graph of the objects in memory?

Comment: @JohnRiope, you can use `session.refresh()` method for that.

Comment: No. That's your responsibility.

Comment: @Chaitanya Useful function! Is there auto-refresh functionality? I am still learning Hibernate, and trying to find my way. I am inclined to think that manually refreshing objects feels _wrong_ in these situations.

Comment: As mentioned by @JBNizet, you have do it manually, there is no auto refresh.

Comment: Thanks both for your useful feedback! I had to pick one answer to accept, since both are less or more the same. I hope you are not offended @Chaitanya.

Comment: never for JBNizet :) he is legend

Answer (score 0):

The other side of the entity where `mappedBy` is not declared is considered as the owner of the association.

So in your code `mappedBy` is declared in `Member`, so the owner of the association is `Project`. So the association will be saved only when you add `Member's` to `Project's`